# How to get frame name of notebook widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

If we have label than we have an option to get it's text as

```
l = tk.Label(text="hello, world")
...
print("the label is", l.cget("text"))
```

But I am unable to find a name of frame added in notebook by the same way is there any other approach available?

[ttk.Notebook](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-notebook) sample:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = tkinter.Tk()
note = Notebook(root)

tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack()
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "name of the frame"? Are  you asking how to get the text of the notebook tab?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes as per Nae s answer i can get on same file but if I am passing dynamically frame object in Nae s answer than it's not working properly here it is Notebook.tab(item)['text'] where item is the dynamic frame object to be resolved

Comment: Please update your question to show us code that accurately reflects the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `text` option of a `tab` of a `ttk.Notebook` by:

```
note.tab(tab2)['text']
```

more generally you can get the `option` of a tab by:

```
nb.tab(tab_name)[option]
```

Comment: That works fine if we are using in same file but if I am passing dynamically one frame element as Notebook.tab(item)['text'] than that is giving TypeError: tab() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tab_id' although I am passing same thing

Comment: Can you please give the reference link for the same for further explore! Thanks

Comment: @мalayмeнтa I used http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Notebook.html

Comment: tabIds seem to default 0 index tuple. You can list text option of all tabs using `for id in range(len(nb.tabs())): nb.tab(id)['text']` for example. Or individually `nb.tab(1)['text']`.

Answer (score 4):

You can give widgets names when you create them:

```
note = Notebook(root, name="George")
tab2 = Frame(note, name="Tabby")
```

and find widgets by name using nametowidget:

```
tab2 = root.nametowidget("George.Tabby")
```